# Проблема установки NODEJS через виртуальную машину с осью ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, virtualbox

Есть windows 10 на нем стоит virtualbox на котором стоит образ ubuntu 16.04. Не устанавливается NODEJS через NVM. Вообще на виртуальной машине есть проблема входа на сайт https://nodejs.org, просто не пускает туда. С основной Оси заходит нормально. В чем может быть проблема? Настраивал сеть как и сетевой мост так и nat соединение не помогло, интернет есть на сайты заходит , но туда не пускает.

Comment: Может прокси есть?

Comment: `ping ya.ru` проходит?

Comment: На другие сайты и пинг проходит и заходит. Не знаю что конкретно помогло. Поставил dsn гугла и перезапустил виртуалку, заработало. Магия какая то.